# Fetch the value from the response data in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Here is my response data,

```
{"system":false,"redirect":{"href":"\/\/localhost-933824.auth.org\/dashboard","data-loader":"fullscreen"},"name":false,"url":"login\/auth\/localhost","container":"#pyModule","scope":null,"infinite":false,"action":{"method":"update","target":"container"},"csrf":{"name":"csrf_token","value":"e18a9gbd853bda5c317cv48a3426y28e"}}
```

Want to fetch `933824` value from the response, how to do it in any extractor like regex or json in Jmeter ? I tried with `[^?]+(?:\?localhost-([^&]+).*)?` and `/\?localhost-([a-z0-9\-]+)\&?/i` but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below, add a regular expression extractor and provide the below expression

`localhost-([^&]*).auth.org`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're making the things too complicated, there is `\d` [meta character](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) which stands for the  "digit" and if you add a `+` sign which stands for "repetition" it will match any number of digits.

So you can simplify your regular expression to something like:

```
localhost-(\d+).auth.org
```

[image]

---

Also be aware that there is even simpler way: using [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) where you don't have to bother about coming up with a proper regular expression, you just need to provide "left" and "right" boundaries and it will extract everything in-between:

[image]

Moreover this approach consumes less resources and acts much faster. More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)